# How to pass parameter to new dataframe for SQL UPDATE using R pool

Tags: r, parameter-passing, pool

I'm trying to pass dataframe to new parameter and then UPDATE to SQL. I'm stuck at passing the paramater

```
library(pool)
library(RMySQL)
library(DT)
library(DBI)

ui <- actionButton("edit_button", "Copy", icon("copy"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #load staff and make reactive to input
  staff <- reactive({
   
    input$submit
    input$submit_edit
   
    dbReadTable(pool, "staff")
    
  }) 

#Form for data entry
  entry_form <- function(button_id){
    
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        div(id=("entry_form"),
            tags$head(tags$style(".modal-dialog{ width:400px}")),
            tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".shiny-split-layout > div {overflow: visible}"))),
            fluidPage(
              fluidRow(
                splitLayout(
                  cellWidths = c("250px", "100px"),
                  cellArgs = list(style = "vertical-align: top"),
                  textInput("userName", labelMandatory("userName"), placeholder = ""),
                  selectInput("picker", "picker", multiple = FALSE, choices = c("", "admin","basic"))
                ),
                textInput("email", "email", width = "354px"),
                selectInput("approval", "approval", multiple = FALSE, choices = c("", "approve", "not approve")),
                selectInput("permission", "permission", multiple = FALSE, choices = c("", "1", "0")),
                helpText(labelMandatory(""), paste("Mandatory field.")),
                actionButton(button_id, "Submit")
              ),
              easyClose = TRUE
            )
        )
      )
    )
  }

  #save form data into data_frame format
  formData <- reactive({
    
    formData <- data.frame(row_id = UUIDgenerate(),
                           userName = input$userName,
                           picker = input$picker,
                           email = input$email, 
                           approval = input$approval,
                           permission = input$permission,
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    return(formData)
    
  })

#edit data
  observeEvent(input$edit_button, priority = 20,{
    
    SQL_df <- dbReadTable(pool, "staff")
    
    showModal(
      if(length(input$staff_table_rows_selected) > 1 ){
        modalDialog(
          title = "Warning",
          paste("Please select only one row." ),easyClose = TRUE)
      } else if(length(input$staff_table_rows_selected) < 1){
        modalDialog(
          title = "Warning",
          paste("Please select a row." ),easyClose = TRUE)
      })  
    
    if(length(input$staff_table_rows_selected) == 1 ){
      
      entry_form("submit_edit")
      
      updateTextInput(session, "userName", value = SQL_df[input$staff_table_rows_selected, "userName"])
      updateSelectInput(session, "picker", selected = SQL_df[input$staff_table_rows_selected, "picker"])
      updateTextInput(session, "email", value = SQL_df[input$staff_table_rows_selected, "email"])
      updateSelectInput(session, "approval", selected = SQL_df[input$staff_table_rows_selected, "approval"])
      updateSelectInput(session, "permission", selected = SQL_df[input$staff_table_rows_selected, "permission"])
      
    }
    
  })
  
  #The dataframe should be passing at this moment
  observeEvent(input$submit_edit, priority = 20, {
    
    SQL_df <- dbReadTable(pool, "staff")
    row_selection <- SQL_df[input$staff_table_row_last_clicked, "userName"] 
    update <- dbExecute(pool, sprintf("UPDATE staff SET 'userName' = ?, 'picker' = ?, 'email' = ?,
                          'approval' = ?, 'permission' = ? WHERE row_id = '%s';", row_selection), 
                          
            param = list(input$userName,
                        input$picker,
                        input$email,
                        input$approval,
                        input$permission),
            )


    
    removeModal()
    
  })
```

When I click submit buttom. A warning appear.

Warning: Error in .local: unused arguments (alist(param = list("haris", "basic", "haris12@gmail.com", "approve", "0"), ))

  80: dbSendQuery

  78: dbSendStatement

 76: DBI::dbExecute

 74: dbExecute

  72: observeEventHandler [C:/Users/Desktop/Task/adminaccess.R#220]

 1: runApp

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've always used `params=`, not `param=`. Could that be causing a problem?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using parameter-binding for five parameters (good!), yet the sixth parameter you are using string-interpolation with `sprintf`? (not good) Just do `dbExecute(pool, "...", params=list(input$userName, ..., row_selection))`.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it still didnt work for me. So my solution is to remove the params and just put the variable into the query.

Answer (score 0):

So, I remove the params and put it in the query. This method worked for me.

```
    observeEvent(input$submit_edit, priority = 20, {
    
    SQL_df <- dbReadTable(pool, "staff")
    row_selection <- SQL_df[input$staff_table_row_last_clicked, "userName"] 
    dbExecute(pool, paste0("UPDATE staff SET userName = '",input$userName,"', picker = '",input$picker,"', email = '",input$email,"',
                          approval = '",input$approval,"', permission = '",input$permission,"' WHERE userName = '",input$userName,"'")
    )
```

Thanks for advices.

Comment: You went from mostly-good (subscribing to "good practices") to not-good (embedding *data* in your query strings). While there are security concerns about malicious [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's a single data analyst running the query. Both `DBI` (with `odbc`) and `RODBC` support [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries).